# Ext4 partition problems

Tags: ext4

I have an 1.5tb external hdd. Yesterday morning it worked well.  The system accidentally freezed, and i restarted the system and i cant mount the partition. 
I removed the hdd from the cage, and used ddrescue to copy the partition image into a file.. 
The copy was successfull without any errors, so the hardware seems ok. 
But i cant mount, the e2fsck freezes as well. If i start, eats some cpu for 1-2 seconds then stops working.

What can i do ? I've read lot of threads, but i havent found anything about this problem. 
If nothing will work, is there any way to rescue few directories ? It would be very very important. At christmas night my main hdd damaged, this hdd was my backup disc. I bought spare hdd  thats why i started to copy files from this disc when this happened, so i dont have any backups.

Comment: it seem i solved the problem, i can mount the partition without journals.

Comment: If you solved your problem, can you please write the solution as an answer and accept it, to let others know how it was solved.

Comment: Possibly the problem was with the jorunalling fs, and fsck and the mount cannot handle the problem well. So i mounted the fs with the following mount flags: -t ext4 -o ro,noload. This worked for me well.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the problem was with the jorunalling fs, and fsck and the mount cannot handle the problem well. So i mounted the fs with the following mount flags: 
-t ext4 -o ro,noload. 
This worked for me well.